# best way to iterate through large 2 column list

Tags: c#

More of a general question. I have a list that looks like below with > 5000 lines. It is currently in a text file but I want to load it into something at app launch to be able to iterate through it faster.

what would be the fastest method? is List<> my only option? or maybe a table?. Not sure what the fastest way to do this is, I need to iterate through it to find a line possibly in the 100s of times per second. Need to find the text after the comma if the number matches the requested number.

If there inst anything which will allow me to iterate through it that fast I may have to look at other options.

```
 913243267,VMBS
 913243268,YAO
 913243269,TLEH
 913243270,EFFE
 913243271,DAX
 913243272,KCNY
 913243273,SHYD
 913243274,BDCL
 913243275,EMLC
 913243276,VCLT
 913243277,VGLT
 913243278,VGSH
```

Comment: How fast is fast enough? Please share a [mcve] of your progress so far. 5000 lines is so small that I think even the dumbest naive solution would be "fast enough".

Comment: I was simply asking in case anyone has tested this. I dont need code, I was just wondering. if someone has done the testing on this it would save me a lot of time writing multiple versions to find the fastest.

Comment: also how fast is fast enough I guess if it gets queries 1000 times a second with 5000 lines thats 5 million loops per second max. To me that sounds like a lot. I dont see it getting there but I would rather program for headroom.

Comment: Probably just populate a `Dictionary<int, string>`? You wouldn't need to iterate, the lookup would be ~O(1) rather than O(n) time complexity.